# SDK 7.1 and SDK 8.0 conflicts in Pivot_SelectionChanged

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to implement changing of ApplicationBar for different PivotItems.

I got following error while defining Pivot type.

```
The type 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Pivot' exists in both 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Libraries\Silverlight\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.dll' and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0\Microsoft.Phone.dll'  D:\projects\MyProject\MyProject\MainPage.xaml.cs
```

I also use AppBarUtils for Internalization, not sure this depends to this library

```C#
private void Pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch ((sender as Pivot).SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            ApplicationBar = ((ApplicationBar)Application.Current.Resources["AppBar1"]);
            break;

        case 1:
            ApplicationBar = ((ApplicationBar)Application.Current.Resources["AppBar2"]);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you tried to upgrade an old app to 8.0.

Here's a MSDN article that helped me upgrade a few.  I remember having a similar problem.

[Upgrade an app project to Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj207030(v=vs.105).aspx)

I think the section you want to read is the "Known Issues" section on the website.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was - I do not remove Reference to SDK 7.1 library Windows.Phone.Controls;